# Почему jquery не работает после динамической подгрузки страницы?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Собственно следующая проблема есть jquery код:

```
$(document).on("ready", function() {
    $('input[advancedtype="searchselect"]').after('<div class="drophelp">TEST</div>');
}
$( '#content' ).load( "form.html"); }

//form.html
<input type='text' advancedtype='searchselect'>
```

Собственно DOM поменялся и TEST не добавляется после подгрузки, как этот момент обойти? кто сталкивался?

Есть какие-то быстрые решения?

Comment: Ну подебажь что ли...

Answer (score 1):

Суть в том, что функции применяемые к DOM после обновления не действительны, так как обновляются все элементы и старые события к ним стираются. Одно из решений - это после каждой загрузки "form.html" снова запускать все функции заново.

Как это сделать? Есть одно лёгкое решение: записать весь нужный код в отдельную функцию и каждый раз её вызывать. Пример:

```js
function func() {
  $('.button0').click(function() {
    alert('Нажалось');
  });
};
$(function() {
  func();
  $('.button1').click(function() {
    $('.but').html('<button class="button0">Обновленная кнопка</button>');
    func();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="but"><button class="button0">Нажми на меня</button></p>
<button class="button1">Обновить</button>
```

Но вообще для событий нажатия, наведения можно использовать глобальные события, но в вашем случае это не уместно. Пример:

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '.button0', function() {
    alert('Нажалось');
  });
  $('.button1').click(function() {
    $('.but').html('<button class="button0">Обновленная кнопка</button>');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="but"><button class="button0">Нажми на меня</button></p>
<button class="button1">Обновить</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Проверяем если контент изменился только тогда добовляем элемент

```
$("body").on('DOMSubtreeModified', "#content", function() {
   $('input[advancedtype="searchselect"]').after('<div class="drophelp">TEST</div>');
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

По событию, сделать `$().remove()`, потом `$().append()`; 
Второй вариант менять по событию через `$().css('display', none)`;